# How to always provide a context for Flask app tested with PyTest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, google-cloud-functions, pytest

I try to implement unit tests with **Pytest** on a **Flask** app and I have a hard time to do it.

My Flask application uses configuration files on most of the functions (here some_method) to illustrate. So it seems that **I should provide a context for each call to any method** that I would like to test. It seems that I can achieve it with "with app.app_context():" on each call.

I read the [official testing documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/testing/) but they talk about creating a client. As I would like to do unit tests, I need to call sub functions which are not top level.

Is there a way to always provide a context without pushing the context manually on each call?

Please find below my current implementation:

*main.py*

```
from flask import current_app


def main(request):
    current_app.config.from_envvar('APPLICATION_SETTINGS')
    print(some_method())
    return 'OK'


def some_method():
    # doing some stuff using the context
    world = current_app.config['SECRET_KEY']
    return world
```

*test_main.py*

```
import pytest
from flask import current_app, Flask

from main import main, some_method

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    # load here any potential configuration configuration
    return app


def test_some_method(app):
    with app.app_context():
        # calling and doing some assertion
        some_method()
```

PS: I do not have app = Flask(*name*) in my main file because I am running on the [Functions Framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pytest-flask](https://pytest-flask.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) seems to configure the context on any call.

*conftest.py*

```
import pytest
from flask import Flask


@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app
```

*test_main.py*

```
import pytest
from flask import current_app, Flask

from main import main, some_method

def test_some_method(app):
    #with app.app_context():
        # calling and doing some assertion
    some_method()
```

works.

Comment: As this seems that is the solution for your initial issue, could you please mark it as accepted to let it know to the community? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following is working for me on pytest 8.0.0.

```py
# conftest.py
import pytest

from flask import Flask
from flask.testing import FlaskClient

@pytest.fixture()
def app() -> Flask:
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    # configure app
    app.config.update({"TESTING": True})

    return app


@pytest.fixture()
def client(app: Flask) -> FlaskClient:
    return app.test_client()


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _provide_app_context(app: Flask):
    with app.app_context():
        yield
```

```py
# test_main.py
from main import some_method


def test_some_method():
    # app context is provided automatically via the _provide_app_context fixture
    some_method()

def test_with_app_and_client_fixtures(app, client):
    pass
```

This may slow down your test runs, so if you're okay with having a shared instance amongst tests, you could cache the app to avoid creating it on each test run. This implementation could be as sophisticated as you'd like, but at the base level, something like the following should work.

```py
# conftest.py
import pytest

from flask import Flask
from flask.testing import FlaskClient

CACHED_APP = Flask(__name__)
CACHED_APP.config.update({"TESTING": True})

@pytest.fixture()
def app() -> Flask:
    return CACHED_APP

# ...
```